# Indexing error in Theano for 3D matrices

Tags: python, numpy, theano, conv-neural-network

I am trying to build a 3D CNN in Theano and I am getting a index of bound error when I am running this nested loops :

```
while(xi < len(xvalues)):
        if(not resumeTraining):
            yi = 0
        while(yi < len(yvalues)):
            if(not resumeTraining):
                zi = 0
                resumeTraining = False
            while(zi < len(zvalues)):
                costTrain = train_model(xvalues[xi],yvalues[yi],zvalues[zi])
                logcost.append(costTrain)
```

Where `plen` = 61 and `offset` = 20 and `training_model` is the following definition:

```
train_model = theano.function(inputs = [idx,idy,idz], outputs = cost,updates = updates, 
                           givens = {x: train_data[:,idx:idx+plen,idy:idy+plen,idz:idz+plen],
                                     z: train_truth[idx+offset/2:idx+plen-offset/2 +1, 
                                                    idy+offset/2:idy+plen-offset/2 +1,
                                                    idz+offset/2:idz+plen-offset/2 +1]})
```

When I run this code I am getting the following errors :

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "runCNNGlioma.py", line 268, in <module>
costTrain = train_model(xvalues[xi],yvalues[yi],zvalues[zi])
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 606, in __call__
storage_map=self.fn.storage_map)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/compile/function_module.py", line 595, in __call__
outputs = self.fn()
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gof/op.py", line 768, in rval
r = p(n, [x[0] for x in i], o)
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/tensor/subtensor.py", line 2214, in perform
inplace_increment(out[0], tuple(inputs[2:]), inputs[1])
IndexError: index 4 is out of bounds for axis 1 with size 3
Apply node that caused the error: AdvancedIncSubtensor{inplace=False,   set_instead_of_inc=False}(Alloc.0, TensorConstant{(74088,) o...34975e-05},  TensorConstant{[    0    ..086 74087]}, Reshape{1}.0)
Inputs types: [TensorType(float32, matrix), TensorType(float32, vector), TensorType(int64, vector), TensorType(int32, vector)]
Inputs shapes: [(74088, 3), (74088,), (74088,), (74088,)]
Inputs strides: [(12, 4), (4,), (8,), (4,)]
Inputs values: ['not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown', 'not shown']

Backtrace when the node is created:
File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/theano/gradient.py", line 1089, in access_term_cache
input_grads = node.op.grad(inputs, new_output_grads)
```

If anyone is interested in the entire code it can be found [here](https://github.com/abhijith2693/iitmFinalYearProject/blob/master/CNNGlioma/runCNNGlioma.py)

Comment: The error is in the symbolic computation but that is too voluminous to identify the fault without running it. I suggest using Theano's `test_value` feature to track down the cause location and update the question with more specific information.

Comment: I used the `test_value`  in warn mode and have updated the error message.

Comment: That extra information doesn't help. It looks to me like you've not used the `test_value` feature properly. Change it to `raise` mode and make sure you provide a value on the `tag.test_value` of all input tensors.